# Composition API template not updating reactive object in non SFC mode

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a simple Vue app that creates a reactive object with a field. Then upon button click, the field on the object is updated. However the template is not updating the updated field. Any hints on what I'm doing wrong? I'm using the esm-browser mode. When I switch it to Options API, then the reactivity works.

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<html>

<head></head>

<body>

<div id="app"></div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.23"></script>
<script src="index.js" type="module"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

```js
//index.js

import { reactive } from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3.2.23/dist/vue.esm-browser.prod.js";

Vue.createApp(
{
    template: `<div>{{ model.firstName }} <p><button @click="buttonClicked">click me</button></p></div>`,
    setup() {
        let model = reactive({ firstName: "test" });

        let buttonClicked = () => {
            model.firstName = "something new";
            console.log(model); // This shows "model" as a Proxy object with the firstName updated. However {{ model.firstName }} is not updated.
        };

        return { model, buttonClicked, };
    }
}
).mount("#app");
```

Comment: For me it works well with the setup block: [link](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to specifically get this to work without a build process.

Comment: I figured it out. I changed the import statement to "const { reactive } = Vue;" and it works now.